# Cannot edit data or delete row in table (pgAdmin)

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am new to pgAdmin and i want to delete a row in a table directly inside pgAdmin. ChatGPT tells me I should be able to do this, either by a query

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = 'desired_value';
```

(I've tried the code both with and without double hyphen around both coloumn_name and table_name)

...or by simply selecting and right-clicking on the row and pressing drop/delete.
But nothing pops up when i right-click. I also can't edit the data. I does not allow me to make edits.
I created the tables myself so I know i have the privileges (I also checked security to make sure I have the privileges).

[image: The view looks like this]

I keep getting the same error when trying to delete a row from the table:

`ERROR:  relation "dag_adressedar_241123" does not exist`
`LINE 1: DELETE FROM "dag_adressedar_241123"`

When i google it, it tells me I'm likely spelling the table name wrong, but I AM NOT. I just copy/paste the table name from its properties.

Finally I can note that a view is dependent on the table, but I don't know if that makes a difference. I tried deleting the view and it still won't let me delete or edit.

Can anyone tell me why it isn't letting me edit or delete rows?

Best regards